# Put a watermark on a .pdf document that is only visible when printed and is not visible when viewing the document?

Tags: itext

Is there a way to use iTextSharp to put a watermark on a .pdf document such that the watermark is only visible when printed and is not visible when viewing the document?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022972/pdf-watermark-for-printing-only-programatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible solutions:

Solution 1: use an OCG layer. OCG stands for Optional Content Groups. It means that you can add content that is optional. Take a look at this example: [layer_structure.pdf](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part4/chapter15/layer_structure.pdf)

It contains some text that is shown on the screen "PRINT THIS PAGE". If you print the document, this text won't be visible. You need the exact opposite, but that's only a matter of changing the settings of the OCG to which the text belongs. See [OptionalContentExample](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=265) for the source code. Go to the [C# port](http://tinyurl.com/iiacsCH15) if you don't understand Java.

Solution 2: Use an annotation and set the visibility of the annotation in such a way that it's not shown on screen, only when printed.

Note that this question is a duplicate of [PDF Watermark for printing only, programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022972/pdf-watermark-for-printing-only-programatically)