# XSL-FO display watermark only when printed

Tags: pdf, xsl-fo

Using XSL-FO, is it possible to add a watermark to a document that is visible only when it is printed?

MY XSL-FO output format is PDF.

I suspect that the answer is no, but I would love to hear different.

Comment: It is not a question for XSL FO. Your question is whether any PDF can be can be created that way. Do you have an example PDF created with any technology that does this?

Comment: I don't personally have an example PDF that supports this, but as per this comment on another question http://stackoverflow.com/a/10044409/1423896 it should be possible by "wrapping the watermark in a PDF layer (Optional Content Group), then configuring the Usage attribute of this layer as Print-Only." Problem is, I don't know how to create a layer and set Usage from within XSL-FO. The system I am using only allows me to specify XSL-FO, and not other options in the PDF generation process.

Comment: IMHO, it would only function for PDF viewers/print mechanisms that support layers. Unless you are also forcing all end users to only use Adobe Reader, then the solution likely will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AH Formatter from Antenna House can produce PDF with print-only layers as you describe.  See http://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf60/docs/ahf-ext.html#pdf-layer

You could put the print-only watermark in one of the side regions and use `axf:layer` to make it appear on a layer that you have set up to be print-only.

Answer (score 1):

There is a free renderer named altsoft xml2pdf that supports layers, see https://www.alt-soft.com/tutorial/xslfo_tutorial/xsl-fo_extensions_pdf-layer.html
I use this renderer for regular production since years, but its windows only.